# Проверить, содержит ли в себе коллекция элементы другой

Tags: java

Есть коллекции:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("1");
list.add("2");

ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
list1.add("3");
list1.add("1");
list1.add("2");
list1.add("4");
list1.add("1");
```

Есть ли какой-нибудь метод, чтобы проверить, содержит ли в себе `list1` все элементы `list`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, [есть](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#containsAll-java.util.Collection-):

```
if (list1.containsAll(list)) {
    // ...
}
```